# How to ignore DST change in Joda DateTime.plusDate function

Tags: java, jodatime, dst

I am using the below code to add 1 day.

```
DateTime userOriginalStartDate = new DateTime(shiftStartEndDuration.getStart());
userOriginalStartDate = userOriginalStartDate.plusDays(1);
```

when my time is 07 march 2015 8:00 (on 8th march DST change) it change to 08 march 2015 9:00.
It is adding 1 hour extra because of DST but i have already calculated DST so at this place i want to ignore this change.
Is there any way to ignore the DST change

Answer (score 2):

Use `LocalDateTime` instead which doesn't carry Timezone information, do the addition and then convert back to `DateTime`.

```
LocalDateTime localUserOriginalStartDate = new LocalDateTime(shiftStartEndDuration.getStart());
DateTime userOriginalStartDate = localUserOriginalStartDate.plusDays(1).toDateTime();
```